# SQL Pivot query in single row

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL query to get data my requirement is row to column:

```
SELECT 
    PM.PageId, PM.PageName, ISNULL(UPA.IsAccess, 0) AS IsAccess
FROM 
    tblPageMaster PM
LEFT JOIN 
    tblUserPageAccess UPA ON UPA.PageId = PM.PageId AND UPA.UserId = 74
WHERE 
    PM.ModuelId = 2
```

Output

```
PageId  PageName      IsAccess
------------------------------
   1    Dashboard1      1
   2    Dashboard2      0
   3    Dashboard3      1
   -- N --
```

Required output

```
Dashboard1      Dashboard2      Dashboard3     -- N --
-------------------------------------------------------
    1                0              1      ---
```

Please see this screenshot:

[image: Please see image]

Comment: See my answer below here you have to only add where condition. I have also attached the live demo link.

Comment: Have a look at `cross apply`

Comment: For all intents and purposes though, all you want is the rows and columns switched here. Can't you do that in your consuming application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following dynamic pivot query.

```
create table temp
(
  PageId int,
  PageName Varchar(20),
  IsAccess int
)

insert into temp values (1,   'Dashboard1',  1), (2,   'Dashboard2',   0), (3,   'Dashboard3',  1)

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.PageName) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select IsAccess, PageName
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(IsAccess)
                for PageName in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

The output is as shown below

```
Dashboard1  Dashboard2  Dashboard3
----------------------------------
1           0           1
```

[**Live Demo Here**](https://rextester.com/XAN56377)