# How to use pivot function in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table like this:

```
Factory indexcode grade
200         1                95
200         2               100
5000        1                85
5000        3                90
```

How can I get this result?

```
Factory.       1        2       3      
200           95     100        -
5000          85       -        90
```

The `indexcode` varies between 1 to 6.

Comment: Have you googled "sql server pivot"?

Comment: You can check this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54247916/sql-pivot-query-in-single-row/54248008#54248008

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
select factorycode,pv.*
from tablename
pivot
(max(grade) for indexcode in ([1],[2],[3])) as pv
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `indexcodes` are fixed (1-6) in that case you can use following PIVOT query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE_NAME
       PIVOT ( Max(grade) 
             FOR indexcode IN ( [1], [2], [3],[4],[5],[6]) ) pvt
```

If your index code values are not fixed and can take any value, in that case you can go for dynamic pivot like following.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(max) = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Quotename(indexcode) 
         FROM TABLE_NAME
         FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''); 

DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(max) = ' SELECT *
                                    FROM  TABLE_NAME
                                           PIVOT ( max(grade) 
                                                 FOR indexcode IN ('+@cols+') ) pvt';
EXECUTE(@query)
```

[DEMO](https://rextester.com/FNA54711)